# How is energy lost?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, energy-conservation

I can understand that if force is applied in the same direction as the motion of the object, energy is transferred to the object in the form of kinetic energy. However, what I don't understand is how is energy lost? For example, if I am exerting a force onto a moving object in the opposite direction, how is energy of the object lost?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/647804/2451

Answer (score 2):

This is a common question that generally occurs when the concepts of force, energy and momentum get somewhat confused. Force is nothing more than an entity that causes an object to change in velocity (either increase or decrease).  In classical terms it is expressed as $F = ma$.  Where $F$ is the force, $m$ is the mass of the object and $a$ is the acceleration (or the change in velocity over time – which can be either an increase or decrease in velocity).

Kinetic Energy $KE= \frac12mv^2$, where $m$ is the mass of the object and $v$ is the velocity.

Momentum $p= mv$ where $m$ is the mass and $v$ is the velocity.

I suspect the difficulty that you are having is that you are trying to use the concept of force as if the force itself contains some energy to transfer.  You therefore can envision a force transferring energy into an object but are having difficulty in seeing how a force applied to an object can reduce its energy.  This line of reasoning is incorrect.  A force, in and of itself, contains no energy.

Let's restrict our conversation to contact forces.  Two entities collide and as a result the velocities of the objects change.  Since the velocities have changed, a force has been applied.  In this case, assuming it is an elastic collision (that is all the energy remains as kinetic energy) you can think of energy as being transferred from one object to the other.  One object will gain energy and the other will loose energy.  So you see in this way that it is possible to apply a force to an object and have that result in the loss of energy.  That is, one object will gain energy while the other will loose energy, but the total energy will remain the same.

However, this analysis is not really complete until we also look at momentum.  Momentum is always conserved so that the total momentum of the system (the two objects) before the collision must also be the same of the momentum of the system after the collision.

To summarize, force simply describes the change in velocity (over time) for an object.  The object can increase or decrease in velocity as a result of the force.
When you look at it this way, it is clear that an object that loses velocity also loses kinetic energy as a result of the force acting on it.  But that lost energy is not missing. And, in the case of an elastic collision, the total kinetic energy and total momentum of the system is always conserved.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your answer using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future posts, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Always remember that, if some system $A$ is losing energy, then it is doing **positive** work on some other system $B$, such that the amount of work done is equal to the amount of energy transferred. A synonymous sentence for the above would be, if some system $A$ is losing energy, them some other system $B$ must be doing negative work on $A$.

For example, when an object moves on a rough surface, the friction does negative work on it, so the amount of work done by friction is the energy lost by the moving object, and since it's moving, the energy that it must lose will be in form of kinetic energy. You can also look it from the objects point of view. The object is constantly doing a positive work against friction to overcome it, and thus the amount of work done is lost from it in terms of kinetic energy.